# Discord.js mention players on welcome

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, mention

a few days ago i made a code to mention users when they join my discord server, this is the code i currently have:

```
bot.on( "guildMemberAdd", member => {
let textChannel = member.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.id === '569582472812298240');

if (textChannel){
        var messages = [
            `Brace yourselves. <@${member.user.id}> just joined the server.`,
            `Challenger approaching - <@${member.user.id}> has appeared`,
            `Welcome <@${member.user.id}>. Leave your weapon by the door.`,
            `Big <@${member.user.id}> showed up!`,
            `<@${member.user.id}> just joined... or did they?`,
            `Ready player <@${member.user.id}>`,
            `<@${member.user.id}> hopped into the server. Kangaroo!!`,
            `<@${member.user.id}> joined. You must construct additional pylons.`,
            `Hello. Is it <@${member.user.id}> you're looking for?`,
            `Where's <@${member.user.id}> in the server!`,
            `It's dangerous to go alone, take <@${member.user.id}>`
        ]

        textChannel.send({embed: {
            color: 3447003,
            description: messages[ Math.floor( Math.random() * 11 ) ],
            timestamp: new Date(),
        }
        }); 
    }
});
```

The problem? Sometimes i get the correct nickname of the person as you can see in this picture, but other times i get just  numbers and i can't even click on that 'link'...

**Correct way:**

They are clickable and i can see their profile.

[image]

**Incorrect way:**

I can't click their id, nothing can be done with it.

[image]

Not sure why this happens randomly, any help would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If someone joins the server and then leaves, and you have no other mutual servers with them and are not their friend, it'll just show their user id. This is a client side thing and there isn't really any real fix for mentions. You can however opt to just send their username instead of a mention.

Answer (score 0):

You could try running toString on the member object, as it will automatically generate the right mention (as sometimes it can be prepended with `<@!`), but the likely reason it still won't work is because your Discord client did not cache the user that just joined.

It can be either because you're in a log channel, the server has too many members or the member left before your Discord client cached the user. You can either try to not use an embed, or (probably the best solution) provide the full username as well as the mention in the embed.

Comment: `<@&...>` represents a role. The problem is actually the client (you) in Discord, not the bot. It does have to do with Discord caching the user but not within the bot. You can reproduce this on your own if you join with an alt, mention it, then kick it and reload Discord. If you're not friends, don't have a DM channel open, and have no servers in common, the mention will no longer work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    var ran = randomRange(0,2);
    var greeting;
    switch (ran) {
        case 0:
            greeting = "Brace yourselves. " + member.user + " just joined the server.";
            break;
        case 1:
            greeting = "Challenger approaching - " + member.user + " has appeared";
            break;
        case 2:
            greeting = "Welcome " + member.user + ". Leave your weapon by the door.";
            break;
        // add more if you want (but dont forget to also change the values in line 2
    }

    member.guild.channels.get('CHANNEL ID HERE').send(greeting);
});
```

And add this function:

```
function randomRange(min, max) { // returns an int >= min and <= max
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```